# Ka/Ks (dN/dS) analysis module for Python?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, natural-selection, sequence-analysis, protein-evolution

From [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka/Ks_ratio):

> In genetics, the **Ka/Ks ratio** (or ω, dN/dS), is the ratio of the number
>   of Nonsynonymous substitutions per non-synonymous site (Ka) to the
>   number of synonymous substitutions per synonymous site (Ks), which can
>   be used as an indicator of selective pressure acting on a
>   protein-coding gene.

**Question:**

Are there any modules/packages available in **Python** for doing Ka/Ks analysis? I wish to carry out whole gene Ka/Ks analysis and then maybe "codon level" Ka/Ks analysis (i.e. within gene via sliding window).

Answer (score 6):

Do you know about [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page)?

[Here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/3YdMAdgIaqmtVzgUXRSS), on another website, someone already asked this question and a pretty nice answer was provided by Brad Chapman. He gives already written functions to perform this kind of analysis (I personally haven't tried the codes).

In Perl there is Bio::Align::DNAStatistics. You might adapt it to Python.

[This](http://snpeff.sourceforge.net) might be useful as well.

I think there are plenty of possibilities that are offered to you. You can go through some others by doing google search with the keywords `synonymous`, `non-synonymous` and `BioPython`.

Comment: Cheers, i'll give this a go soon!

Comment: I've looked into BioPython, they have an output parser for PAML but that software is not recommended when you only have pairs of protein sequences. I ended up programming my own version which implements the approximate Nei-Gojobori algorithm.